# Batch - Leading 0's on Day and Month

Tags: batch-file

Fairly simple I have this script that gets me the current time and saves it to a file:

```
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
echo today=%Year%-%Month%-%Day% > env.properties
```

The only problem is the date comes out as `2017-3-9` and I'm not sure on how I would make it add the leading 0 onto the month and day so I get this instead `2017-03-09`

Comment: Use this instead. `wmic OS Get localdatetime /value`  This will give you the date and time but will be in the format YYYYMMDDhhmmss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets the date and time but also has your leading zeros for all the fields. You can obviously just use one SET command to get the values you need.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
```

Comment: Just a cautionary note for anyone this might apply to: once you've got leading zeroes on the various components, it's hard to do maths (e.g. `set /a NEXTMONTH=MM+1`) because `set /a` treats a leading zero as meaning octal, and `08`, say, is invalid octal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wmic PATH Win32_LocalTime get` to retrieve the date in the format you want, but you need to prepend the zero in your `for /F` loop then. Here is a working solution:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%Z in ('wmic PATH Win32_LocalTime get Day^,Month^,Year /FORMAT:LIST') do (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%X in ("%%Z") do set "%%X=0%%Y"
)
> "env.properties" echo today=%Year:~-4%-%Month:~-2%-%Day:~-2%
```

Besides defining the option string `tokens1* delims==`, changing the assignment statement `set` and expanding the desired amount of digits in the `echo` command, I changed some more things:

- I retrieve the needed values `Day`, `Month` and `Year` only, because your `wmic` command line returned a lot of other values which are not needed then.
- Instead of `findstr "="` to filter out lines that appear empty, I wrapped around another `for /F` loop; actually those lines are not empty but contain orphaned carriage-return characters, which result from poor conversation to ANSI of the Unicode `wmic` output by `for /F`; actually also the non-empty lines contain trailing carriage-return characters; the second `for /F` loop gets rid of all of these conversion artefacts.
- The redirection syntax has been reversed in order not to have a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> written to the output file `env.properties`.

---

Of course you can switch to the command line `wmic OS get LocalDateTime` as [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694) suggested in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42721336), but I still recommend to wrap around another `for /F` loop to avoid the aforementioned conversion artefacts (although the trailing carriage-return characters do not harm here as you are expanding sub-strings at the beginning of the whole string in this situation):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%Z in ('wmic OS get LocalDateTime /VALUE') do (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%X in ("%%Z") do set "DATETIME=%%Y"
)
> "env.properties" echo today=%DATETIME:~,4%-%DATETIME:~4,2%-%DATETIME:~6,2%
```